# Error in smooth.spline: missing or infinite values in inputs are not allowed

Tags: r, spline

I'm trying to apply smoothing using `smooth.spline` and I keep getting this error. I have excluded `NA` from the data frame. Here is a sample of my data:
[test1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10jqGzXHyFcUHtXVnfJQNLdLddbi1urZAbHmeQH-kjKk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv)

Code:

```
fit.sp<- smooth.spline(test1)
fitted_values <-fit.sp$fit$coef
```

Error:

```
 Error in smooth.spline(median_weeknum, test1) : 
    missing or infinite values in inputs are not allowed
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! While trying to re post the question I tried the package `zoo`. I was using the loop on quite a few data sets. I think the smoothing function was creating `knots` around `NA` values where it did not find any existing `x` value. Using `na.spline()` I created values around these zones and it solved the problem!